# Mount Azure file share from an on-premises client through VPN

Tags: azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I have created a Azure file storage/share and I would like to mount a drive letter (net use) to this share from an on-premises client (Windows 10).
Since my ISP is blocking port 445 I'm not able to mount the file share direct.

I have created a Azure Virtual Network and VPN Gateway and I'm able to make the point-to-site connection without any problem, but I cannot mount the file share.

Should it be possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to configure your VPN / NAT to route the specific URL of your Azure file share via the VPN tunnel

Comment: Is routing enough? I mean... will it work if right configured or is it unsupported? How should I config routing to get it to work?

Comment: It will work with the right routing. Configuration method will depend on your specific VPN client. Take a look at "route" command on Windows. Basically, you need to ADD a route for your Azure File ip, pointing to your VPN gateway.

Comment: I did add a route on my local pc. When I run tracert to my file storage service I can see that first hop is going the right direction... but it only makes one jump, then I get "timed out". Do I have to route in Azure VPN service also? Are you sure it's doable? Have you been able to verify it?

Comment: (Did tracert work without the VPN routing? Since it uses UDP, that may not be same as the port 445 issue. Is the time out from ISP?) You don't need routing in Azure VPN. My guess is, you may need additional tweaking of the routing rules.

Comment: Without routing tracert also timed out (after 9 hops). But I just discovered my mistake... VPN gateway is created in Classic portal and File storage is done in Resource manager, so I understand that it will not work until I use same deployment model. I will give this a new shot when P2S Gateway is available in ARM. Thanks for your help.